# Как настроить корректное отображение кириллицы и ansi форматирования в консоли запуска команд PhpStorm

Tags: windows, phpstorm, laravel5

Использую PhpStorm для Windows. Большинство проектов, с которыми приходится работать созданы на Laravel. После выхода версии 2019.2, когда «Run command» заменили «Run once» столкнулся с проблемой, которой не было в предыдущих версиях и которую не могу решить до сих пор, а именно: заставить корректно отображаться кириллицу и ansi форматирование в консоли запуска команд.

Вот пример того, как на данный момент выглядит вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли на данный момент какой-либо способ решить эту проблему?

**UPD**: Хочу уточнить, что речь в вопросе идет не об инструменте `Terminal`, который еще хоть как-то можно настраивать. Речь о вкладке `Run`, в которой выводятся результаты запуска команд через меню `Tools->Run Command`(или `Ctrl+Shift+X`) и вывод в которую формируется, судя по всему, в самом PhpStorm и непонятно каким образом его можно настраивать.

**UPD**: Судя по всему, проблема с ansi форматированием существует только для устаревших версий Laravel, например, 5.2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В то время, как в проекте с версией 5.7 вывод происходит нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/16a85b3c2cd84eaa7d395627d9bce35d

Подскажите, у Вас cmd или устанавливали bash? Разница от этого существенная в кодировке.

Comment: Стандартный инструментарий Windows, дополнительно ничего не устанавливал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему с отображением кириллицы можно решить следующим образом:
Откройте с помощью пункта главного меню `Help->Edit custom VM options` файл с настройками ВМ. Проверьте, чтобы в нем находились следующие строки:

```
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Если какой-либо нет - добавьте ее и перезапустите PhpStorm.

Что касается проблемы с форматированием, то ее, судя по всему, на данный момент решить невозможно. Скорее всего, проблема имеет место только при использовании морально устаревших версий Laravel (в моем случае - 5.2) и не является массовой. Единственное, что можно посоветовать в данном случае - совсем отключать форматирование вывода, где это возможно. Например, при использовании команды `artisan` форматирование можно отключить с помощью флага `--no-ansi`:

```
php artisan --no-ansi
```

В данном случае при выводе результата выполнения команды форматирование использоваться не будет и текст станет хотя бы удобочитаемым.

Answer (score 2):

Всё поправимо. 
Если bash, то необходимо создать файл .bash_profile, в котором необходимо указать нужную кодировку. На подобии.

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"; export LANG
or (or both)
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"; export LC_ALL
```

Если же cmd

```
Start->Run->regedit
Go to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
Change the “OEMCP” value to “1251”
Requires computer restart
```

Если zsh или csh, советую посмотреть [Тут](https://superuser.com/questions/1108443/utf8-characters-in-windows-10-bash-terminal)

Comment: Использую стандартный cmd.exe. К сожалению, изменение указанного значения реестра ни к чему не привела.

Comment: в windows запустите cmd.exe и наберите chcp какую кодировку покажет

Comment: `Текущая кодовая страница: 1251` Обратите внимание также на дополнение к вопросу.

Comment: @P.Fateev проверьте, пожалуйста, ещё параметр справа снизу https://pastenow.ru/d7ee9fa7bded3950c59d9ffe7d868da9   Должен стоять UTF-8. Можно при смене использовать (convert) После добавления дополнения к вопросу, предполагаю, что проблема именно в vm. Попробуйте изменить конфигурацию Help → Edit Custom VM Options

Comment: проблему с отображением кириллицы удалось решить, добавив `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` в файл конфигурации VM. Но с ANSI проблема так и осталась.

Comment: А какой у Вас стоит general encoding? https://pastenow.ru/40859c5cc3f4ebc146ae822047c944d2

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102487/discussion-between-p-fateev-and-denis640kb).